# How-to get the full path file of IOException with Error Sharing Violation

Tags: c#, file, error-handling, ioexception, sharing-violation

I get an IOException with ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION = 32, and I want get the full path file is "locked".

```
    var ioex = ex as IOException;

    var err = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    if (err == 32) Trace.WriteLine("It's locked");
```

The exception message can be in several languages:

> The process cannot access the file
> 'C:\Users\mj.PG\Documents\IssuedLetter\3.PDF' because it is being used
> by another process.
>
> El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo
> '\xxxx.es\xxxxx\Campañas SVT\Campaña
> zzzz\Coordinacion\4_ESTADISTICAS\2021\05_mayo\Informes Servicio
> zzzz\Informe Acumulado\Informe Acumulado 05_05_2021.xlsx' porque está
> siendo utilizado en otro proceso.

How-to get the full path file without use the string?

Comment: Typically one would know the file they were trying to access.  Is that option not available?  `IOException` does not provide any way of finding out the file other than parsing the message which is, admittedly, not ideal.

Comment: Perhaps look in the `Data` property?